# Why in jsfiddle display ReferenceError: function is not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My code in jsfiddle is like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/1xstdra1/

When I run the script in jsfiddle, in console exist error like this : `ReferenceError: doPagination is not defined`. Whereas when I tried on my localhost, it works. no error

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you

Comment: Try this one: https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/xojyvvmw/

Comment: @Joseph Marikle, It's working. Thank you very much

Comment: To clarify, I changed the jsFiddle option "Load Type" under the JavaScript menu from `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <body>`.  Your `doPagination` function was out of scope.

Comment: @Joseph Marikle, Ok. Thank you very much

Comment: The error disappeared when I logged in!

Answer (score 4):

The jQuery library is not included. You can do this by clicking the settings button in the javascript field, and then select a version of jQuery at "Frameworks and extensions".

Comment: This solves the problem in title but not the problem in the question. :P

Comment: It probably is the reason for the other error as well. If the jQuery error occured somewhere in the `doPagination` function, the function will probably not be defined, making the error.

Comment: doPagination was a user defined function that was out of scope based on how jsFiddle includes the javascript into the output by default.  Changing that setting corrected OPs issue.